# "Diplomacy" rule clarification, unit under attack

Tags: diplomacy

Referring to the original game.

If a unit is under attack from Province X, can it still interfere with the actions of a unit on Province Y?

For example:

1. *English* fleet unit on "English Channel" ordered to **convoy** an army unit
2. *French* fleet unit on "Mid Atlantic Ocean" ordered to **move** to "English Channel"
3. *English* fleet unit on "Irish Sea" ordered to **move** to "Mid Atlantic Ocean"

I think that the order #3 should keep the fleet unit at "Mid Atlantic Ocean" busy in the stand off and thus not able to interfere with the convoy. I've been told this is not the case but we could not find verification in the rule book. Can someone please explain?

Here is an [image of the Diplomacy board](http://www.dipwiki.com/images/3/31/Standard_map_c.gif) if it helps:

Comment: No need to edit your question to indicate you've answered it. Someone else may still come up with a better/different answer. Also, if you are satisfied, you can accept your own answer to indicate this (click the green checkmark next to the answer).

Comment: That's my map!  I'm surprised people are still using it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All good. Only way to disrupt a convoy is to dislodge the convoying fleet unit. So even if order #3 was not present, the convoy action would proceed

Comment: Do you have a reference for this answer that you could link to?

Comment: http://www.wizards.com/avalonhill/rules/diplomacy.pdf - page 12, section "Disrupting a Convoy"
(I was too busy looking at other sections about cutting support and what not)

Comment: There is a rather complicated convey chain you can set up which results in a paradox under the rules, as the army will cut support from its destination if it is convoyed, but if its cutting an allies support to keep its convoying fleet in place then the fleet will be dislodged, so the convoy doesn't happen, which means the support isn't cut...

Answer (score 1):

No, a **movement is not interrupted by an attack**. Nor is a convoy, per se.

But the attack on the convoy is still **not strong enough to prevent it**! Unlike supports (which you can interfere with by a single attack, by std rules) a convoy is only interrupted **if the convoying fleet has to retreat**.

A support would be interrupted, though. It would be changed to a hold order (and could be supported as such)

Just some hypothetical additions to your scenario:

- <del>`F MID-ENG`</del> is an *unsuccessful move* which has a defense strength (in its start region) of 1. (In standard diplomacy all unsuccessful moves have a defense strength of 1. Since you can not *support to hold* a unit that is *ordered to move* this is always the case when the move is blocked.)
- <del>`F IRA-MID`</del> is therefore also just an *unsuccessful move*, because it has not enough strength to dislodge `F MID`.
- A convoy `F ENG con A Bel-Lon` is therefore successful.
- Even it there were an additional support of `F Bre sup F IRA-MID` which would dislodge `F MID` and the convoy would be successful.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, a fleet that exists in a "square" can't be dislodged by the attack of a single fleet. But a fleet under attack in a square is prevented from supporting ANOTHER fleet.
Without help, the fleet in the MidAtlantic Ocean can't dislodge a hostile fleet in the English channel on convoy duty. But if that fleet were supporting say, an allied fleet in the North Sea, the attack from the Midatlantic would "cut" the North Sea support.

Likewise, the fleet in the Irish sea can't dislodge the enemy fleet in the Midatlantic ocean. At least not without the help of the fleet in the English Channel. But then THAT fleet could not conduct convoy duty on the same turn.

Answer (score 0):

> If a unit is under attack from Province X, can it still interfere with the actions of a unit on Province Y?

Yes, but the only action you can 'interfere' with is support, and only against other provinces.  So in this case if the unit in province Y had a support order OTHER than supporting an attack against this unit, it would be cut.

In your case, Y has a Convoy order, which is unaffected by an attack that doesn't dislodge it.

Comment: Don't forget that you can cut support for attacking X if you successfully dislodge Y.